# convert multiple rows to one column while skip specific lines that start with work( in python or shell )

Tags: python, shell

I have text file look like this

```
GRID   xxxxx   yyyyy   zzzzz
1111    1111    1111    1111    1111
2222    2222    2222    2222    2222
GRID   xxxxx2   yyyyy2   zzzzz2
1111    1111    1111    1111    1111
2222    2222    2222    2222    2222
```

I want to  convert it to become like this

```
GRID   xxxxx   yyyyy   zzzzz
1111
1111
1111
1111
2222
2222
2222
2222
GRID   xxxxx2   yyyyy2   zzzzz2
1111
1111
1111
1111
2222
2222
2222
2222
```

And it will be great if it become like this

`GRID   xxxxx   yyyyy   zzzzz
1    zzzzz   1111   xxxxx   yyyyy
2    zzzzz   1111   xxxxx   yyyyy
3    zzzzz   1111   xxxxx   yyyyy
4    zzzzz   1111   xxxxx   yyyyy
5    zzzzz   2222   xxxxx   yyyyy
6    zzzzz   2222   xxxxx   yyyyy
7    zzzzz   2222   xxxxx   yyyyy
8    zzzzz   2222   xxxxx   yyyyy
GRID   xxxxx2   yyyyy2   zzzzz2
1    zzzzz2   1111   xxxxx2   yyyyy2
2    zzzzz2   1111   xxxxx2   yyyyy2
3    zzzzz2   1111   xxxxx2   yyyyy2
4    zzzzz2   1111   xxxxx2   yyyyy2
5    zzzzz2   2222   xxxxx2   yyyyy2
6    zzzzz2   2222   xxxxx2   yyyyy2
7    zzzzz2   2222   xxxxx2   yyyyy2
8    zzzzz2   2222   xxxxx2   yyyyy2`

it's important to meto do that so any add will be very appreciated

I tried as next:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/84XiJ.png

Comment: Please share the work that you have done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Python] I guess this is what you are looking for

```
f = open("testfile.txt",'r')
g = None
x = None
y = None
z = None
count = 0
for line in f:
    if line.startswith("GRID"):
        [g,x,y,z]=line.split()
        count = 1
        print(line.strip())
    else:
        for word in line.split():
            print (str(count),z,word.strip(),x,y)
            count +=1            
f.close()
```

Comment: there may be a chance that i got help with last form

Comment: I update the code check if this is what you expected?

Comment: Really Thanks you very much Sandeep, It works exactly as i need